# How to Install DBD::Oracle in Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, oracle, dbi, strawberry-perl, dbd

I am trying to install [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::Oracle) using the CPAN shell in Strawberry Perl.  I initially experienced an error because the `Makefile` could not locate an `OCI` library, so I installed the instant client from Oracle.  I thought this would fix the problem, but now I get a large mixture of errors and warnings from `Oracle.h`, `dbdimp.h`, `Oracle.c`, `Oracle.xsi`, and `Oracle.xs`.

Any suggestions for how I should proceed?  Is it possible that there is a problem with existing Oracle software on my computer?  I am fairly new to Perl, so any help is appreciated.

**Edit** -- I'm including the entire output below:

```
cpan> install DBD::Oracle
Database was generated on Fri, 04 Dec 2009 16:12:46 GMT
Running install for module 'DBD::Oracle'
Running make for P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.23.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\P\PY\PYTHIAN\DBD-Oracle-1.23.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
...............................................................-------------DONE

  CPAN.pm: Going to build P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.23.tar.gz

Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/ C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 37
Using DBI 1.609 (for perl 5.010001 on MSWin32-x86-multi-thread) installed in C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/
Argument "6.55_02" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at Makefile.PL line 61.

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.010001 on MSWin32 (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Installing on a MSWin32, Ver#5.1
Using Oracle in C:/ORACLE/ORA90
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "900010001" (CHAR)
Oracle version 9.0.1.0 (9.0)
Found oci directory
Using OCI directory 'oci'

Checking for functioning wait.ph


System: perl5.010001 Win32 strawberryperl 5.10.1.0 #1 30 i386
Compiler:   gcc -s -O2  -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DHAVE_DES_FCRYPT  -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -DPERL_
MSVCRT_READFIX
Linker:     not found
Sysliblist:

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
LD_RUN_PATH=C:/ORACLE/ORA90/lib:C:/ORACLE/ORA90/rdbms/lib
Using DBD::Oracle 1.23.
Using DBD::Oracle 1.23.
Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/ C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 1696
Using DBI 1.609 (for perl 5.010001 on MSWin32-x86-multi-thread) installed in C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/
Writing Makefile for DBD::Oracle

***  If you have problems...
     read all the log printed above, and the README and README.help.txt files.
     (Of course, you have read README by now anyway, haven't you?)

cp Oracle.pm blib\lib\DBD\Oracle.pm
cp oraperl.ph blib\lib/oraperl.ph
cp dbdimp.h blib\arch\auto\DBD\Oracle/dbdimp.h
cp ocitrace.h blib\arch\auto\DBD\Oracle/ocitrace.h
cp Oraperl.pm blib\lib/Oraperl.pm
cp Oracle.h blib\arch\auto\DBD\Oracle/Oracle.h
cp lib/DBD/Oracle/Object.pm blib\lib\DBD\Oracle\Object.pm
cp mk.pm blib\arch\auto\DBD\Oracle/mk.pm
cp lib/DBD/Oracle/GetInfo.pm blib\lib\DBD\Oracle\GetInfo.pm
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/Oracle/g" C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI\Driver.xst > Oracle.xsi
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap -typemap typemap  Oracle.xs >
 Oracle.xsc && C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e "mv" -- Oracle.xsc Oracle.c
gcc -c  -IC:/ORACLE/ORA90/oci/include -IC:/ORACLE/ORA90/rdbms/demo -IC:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI       -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DHAVE_DES_FCRYPT -DUSE
_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -DPERL_MSVCRT_READFIX -s -O2      -DVERSION=\"1.23\"    -DXS_VERSION=\
"1.23\"  "-IC:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE"  -Wall -Wno-comment -DUTF8_SUPPORT -DORA_OCI_VERSION=\"9.0.1.0\" Oracle.c
In file included from Oracle.xs:1:
Oracle.h:37:17: oci.h: No such file or directory
Oracle.h:39:20: ocidfn.h: No such file or directory
Oracle.h:40:18: orid.h: No such file or directory
Oracle.h:41:17: ori.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Oracle.h:54,
                 from Oracle.xs:1:
dbdimp.h:16: error: syntax error before "OCIEnv"
dbdimp.h:16: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
dbdimp.h:23: error: syntax error before '}' token
dbdimp.h:37: error: syntax error before "OCIEnv"
dbdimp.h:37: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
dbdimp.h:38: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `errhp'
dbdimp.h:38: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:39: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:39: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `srvhp'
dbdimp.h:39: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:40: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:40: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `svchp'
dbdimp.h:40: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:41: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:41: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `authp'
dbdimp.h:41: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:51: error: syntax error before '}' token
dbdimp.h:66: error: syntax error before "OCIEnv"
dbdimp.h:66: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
dbdimp.h:67: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `errhp'
dbdimp.h:67: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:68: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:68: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `srvhp'
dbdimp.h:68: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:69: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:69: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `svchp'
dbdimp.h:69: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:70: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:70: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `stmhp'
dbdimp.h:70: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:71: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:71: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `dschp'
dbdimp.h:71: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:121: error: syntax error before '}' token
dbdimp.h:143: error: syntax error before "OCIParam"
dbdimp.h:143: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
dbdimp.h:144: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `parmap'
dbdimp.h:144: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:145: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:145: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `tdo'
dbdimp.h:145: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:146: error: syntax error before "typecode"
dbdimp.h:146: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `typecode'
dbdimp.h:146: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:147: error: syntax error before "col_typecode"
dbdimp.h:147: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `col_typecode'
dbdimp.h:147: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:148: error: syntax error before "element_typecode"
dbdimp.h:148: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `element_typecode'
dbdimp.h:148: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:149: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:149: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `obj_ref'
dbdimp.h:149: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:150: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:150: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `obj_ind'
dbdimp.h:150: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:151: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:151: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `obj_value'
dbdimp.h:151: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:152: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:152: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `obj_type'
dbdimp.h:152: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:159: error: syntax error before '}' token
dbdimp.h:166: error: syntax error before "OCIParam"
dbdimp.h:166: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
dbdimp.h:167: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `defnp'
dbdimp.h:167: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:199: error: syntax error before '}' token
dbdimp.h:221: error: syntax error before "OCIBind"
dbdimp.h:221: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
dbdimp.h:238: error: syntax error before '*' token
dbdimp.h:238: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of `array_indicators'
dbdimp.h:238: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
dbdimp.h:246: error: conflicting types for 'name'
dbdimp.h:178: error: previous declaration of 'name' was here
dbdimp.h:247: error: syntax error before '}' token
dbdimp.h:284: error: syntax error before "OCILobLocator"
dbdimp.h:299: error: syntax error before "OCIError"
dbdimp.h:333: error: syntax error before "OCIBind"
dbdimp.h:335: error: syntax error before "OCIBind"
dbdimp.h:338: error: syntax error before "OCIDefine"
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle_constant':
Oracle.c:74: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle_ORA_OCI':
Oracle.c:108: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle_ora_env_var':
Oracle.c:131: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
In file included from Oracle.c:179:
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h: In function `dbdxst_bind_params':
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:60: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:65: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:66: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:67: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h: In function `dbdxst_fetchall_arrayref':
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:93: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:94: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h:101: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__dr_dbixs_revision':
Oracle.c:185: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db__login':
Oracle.c:278: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_selectall_arrayref':
./Oracle.xsi:152: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:320: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_selectrow_arrayref':
./Oracle.xsi:196: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:387: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_commit':
./Oracle.xsi:275: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:275: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:549: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_rollback':
./Oracle.xsi:285: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:285: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:572: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_disconnect':
./Oracle.xsi:295: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:300: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:300: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:302: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:304: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:308: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:308: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:308: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:595: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_STORE':
./Oracle.xsi:322: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:629: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_FETCH':
./Oracle.xsi:334: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:657: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_DESTROY':
./Oracle.xsi:345: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:347: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:347: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:348: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:353: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:354: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:354: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:354: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:355: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:356: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:358: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:359: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:370: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:371: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:372: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:382: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:382: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:382: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:682: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st__prepare':
Oracle.c:830: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_rows':
Oracle.c:869: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_bind_param':
Oracle.c:951: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_bind_param_inout':
Oracle.c:999: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_execute':
./Oracle.xsi:586: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:587: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1053: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_fetchrow_arrayref':
Oracle.c:1125: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_fetchrow_array':
Oracle.c:1150: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_fetchall_arrayref':
Oracle.c:1185: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_finish':
./Oracle.xsi:669: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:670: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:674: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:677: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:677: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:677: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1226: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_blob_read':
Oracle.c:1262: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_STORE':
./Oracle.xsi:717: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1306: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_FETCH_attrib':
./Oracle.xsi:734: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1334: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
./Oracle.xsi: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_DESTROY':
./Oracle.xsi:745: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:747: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:747: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:748: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:753: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:754: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:754: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:754: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:755: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:756: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:758: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:759: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:760: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:768: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:768: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Oracle.xsi:768: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1362: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.xs: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_ora_stmt_type':
Oracle.xs:105: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1418: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.xs: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_ora_stmt_type_name':
Oracle.xs:114: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1443: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.xs: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_ora_scroll_position':
Oracle.xs:127: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1470: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.xs: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_ora_fetch_scroll':
Oracle.xs:140: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:141: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1495: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_ora_bind_param_inout_array':
Oracle.c:1526: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.xs: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_ora_fetch':
Oracle.xs:189: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:189: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:189: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:192: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
Oracle.xs:196: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:198: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:217: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:219: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:219: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1572: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.xs: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_ora_execute_array':
Oracle.xs:234: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:235: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1631: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__st_cancel':
Oracle.c:1678: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.xs: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_ping':
Oracle.xs:273: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCIServerVersion'
Oracle.xs:273: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:273: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:273: error: `OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:273: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Oracle.xs:273: error: for each function it appears in.)
Oracle.xs:273: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:274: error: `OCI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1699: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_reauthenticate':
Oracle.c:1736: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_lob_write':
Oracle.c:1767: error: `OCILobLocator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1767: error: `locator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1782: error: syntax error before ')' token
Oracle.xs:307: error: `SQLCS_IMPLICIT' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:314: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCILobCharSetForm'
Oracle.xs:314: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:314: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:314: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:314: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:315: error: `OCI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:316: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:330: error: `SQLCS_NCHAR' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:332: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCILobWrite'
Oracle.xs:332: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:332: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:332: error: `OCI_ONE_PIECE' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:332: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:332: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:338: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1759: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_lob_append':
Oracle.c:1845: error: `OCILobLocator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1845: error: `locator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1862: error: syntax error before ')' token
Oracle.xs:363: error: `SQLCS_IMPLICIT' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:370: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:370: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:370: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:370: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:371: error: `OCI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:372: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:386: error: `SQLCS_NCHAR' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:387: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCILobWriteAppend'
Oracle.xs:387: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:387: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:387: error: `OCI_ONE_PIECE' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:387: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:387: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:392: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:357: warning: unused variable `startp'
Oracle.c:1837: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_lob_read':
Oracle.c:1923: error: `OCILobLocator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1923: error: `locator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1938: error: syntax error before ')' token
Oracle.xs:417: error: `SQLCS_IMPLICIT' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:427: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:427: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:427: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:427: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:428: error: `OCI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:429: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:433: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCILobRead'
Oracle.xs:433: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:433: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:433: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:433: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:438: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:445: error: `SQLCS_NCHAR' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1915: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_lob_trim':
Oracle.c:1997: error: `OCILobLocator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:1997: error: `locator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2006: error: syntax error before ')' token
Oracle.xs:461: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCILobTrim'
Oracle.xs:461: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:461: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:461: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:461: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:462: error: `OCI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:463: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:1989: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_lob_length':
Oracle.c:2039: error: `OCILobLocator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2039: error: `locator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2048: error: syntax error before ')' token
Oracle.xs:479: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCILobGetLength'
Oracle.xs:479: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:479: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:479: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:479: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:480: error: `OCI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:481: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:2031: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__db_ora_lob_chunk_size':
Oracle.c:2081: error: `OCILobLocator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2081: error: `locator' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2090: error: syntax error before ')' token
Oracle.xs:498: warning: implicit declaration of function `OCILobGetChunkSize'
Oracle.xs:498: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:498: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:498: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:498: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.xs:499: error: `OCI_SUCCESS' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.xs:500: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
Oracle.c:2073: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `XS_DBD__Oracle__dr_init_oci':
Oracle.c:2115: warning: unused variable `Perl___notused'
Oracle.c: In function `boot_DBD__Oracle':
Oracle.c:2157: error: `OCI_FETCH_RELATIVE' undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2171: error: `OCI_FETCH_FIRST' undeclared (first use in this functio
```

Comment: The error you show basically only says that that the compile failed; the errors/warnings *before* that will say why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DBD::Oracle is notoriously difficult to compile, multiplied by Windows, and you're better off just not doing it if you can avoid it.  Unfortunately [ActiveState does not supply a PPM for it for licensing reasons](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#crypto_packages) nor do the other [PPM repositories](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=PPM_Repositories) I looked through.  Though its rumored that [ActivePerl 5.10.0.1003 comes with DBD-Oracle](http://blogs.activestate.com/2008/05/activeperl-5100/).

If your Oracle server supports ODBC, you can talk to it using [DBD::ODBC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-ODBC).

If you want to try, here are some [special instructions for installing DBD::Oracle on Strawberry Perl](https://web.archive.org/web/20090706110437/http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Install_DBD::Oracle_on_Strawberry_Perl) which may be of help.

Comment: I followed your suggestion about using ODBC. I successfully set up an ODBC data source in Windows and used DBD::ODBC to connect to the database. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a rumor. And I've just used ActiveState's ppm to upgrade to DBD-Oracle 1.23.

Comment: Though I don't know why it's not listed at UWinn: http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/search?query=dbd-oracle&mode=dist

Comment: Since following these instructions, the need has arisen to call a PL/SQL package from my Perl code. What is the best way (if there is any at all) to do this via DBD::ODBC?

Comment: The link on the answer is not valid anymore.

Comment: @hasan It seems win32.perl.org is defunct.  I found the content using the Internet Wayback Machine and fixed the link.

Comment: @Schwern, thanks. 

Just a note, Strawberry Perl 5.20 now (since May, 2014) also ships with DBD::Oracle, as long as you install instantclient 11.x version it works out of the box. http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.20.0.1-64bit.html

Comment: @hasan That's good information, you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Strawberry Perl 5.20 (since May, 2014) ships with DBD::Oracle, as long as you install instantclient 11.x version it works out of the box. See http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.20.0.1-64bit.html

> Newly added DBD::Oracle - you have to install 64bit Oracle Instant Client 11.x and make sure you have OCI.DLL in your PATH

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have all of the Oracle source (*.h, *.c) files, you can install DBD::Oracle via ppm, just like ActiveState. Or copy the library files from the ActiveState distribution.

Comment: Great tip ... after battling with for an hour, i just needed to 
ppm install http://trouchelle.com/ppm10/unstable/DBD-Oracle.ppd

Comment: I got it working using this: http://garygoog.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/easy-way-to-install-dbdoracle-for-strawberry-perl/

Answer (score 2):

I documented what worked for me on Win32 [here](http://ba6.us/node/274) on my blog. Actually everything went smoothly except the DBI make process didn't detect my installed Oracle Client version correctly. A little deciphering of the make file and I saw there was a parameter to explicitly specify the version. I had to run the make and install commands manually but it all worked out.

I tried to use some pre-compiled modules but they were compiled with a specific version of Strawberry Perl in mind. I think I found a 5.12 compiled DBI for Oracle and it complained when I tried to use it with the latest 5.16 Strawberry Perl so that's why I went the manual build route.

From here on out I will probably just copy my c:\perl binary directory to other machines I need it, set environment variables and roll with it.

Answer (score 0):

After setting environment variables `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and adding the Oracle `bin` folder to `PATH` it worked fine without any problem for me.

```
set PATH=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\bin;%PATH%
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\bin
set ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64

cpan
install DBD::Oracle
```

Maybe not all three of them are required. Anyway, they are set only while you install the module.