# Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::Oracle in @INC : Cygwin

Tags: oracle, perl, cygwin, dbd

I am using cygwin on windows to compile perl modules. I was able to install perl DBI through cpan later I installed DBD , it aslo said successfully installed.

> cpan[1]> install DBD::Oracle Going to read
>   '/home/e1sched/.cpan/Metadata'   Database was generated on Wed, 24 Apr
>   2013 12:08:01 GMT DBD::Oracle is up to date (1.60).

Now when i execute my script, i am getting this error below.

> $ ./invpayhistload.sh 5 50000 Thu, Apr 25, 2013  5:53:31 AM Begin
>   batch process PPID 7580 install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't locate
>   loadable object for module DBD::Oracle in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14
>   /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/5.14
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 .) at (eval 3) line 3 Compilation failed
>   in require at (eval 3) line 3. Perhaps a module that DBD::Oracle
>   requires hasn't been fully installed  at
>   /usr/local/batch/bin/invpayhistload.pl line 33

DBD::Oracle seems to have not installed properly. I tried many times but the result is same. Is there a problem with finding the path? what is this `@INC`? Appreciate your reply.

Comment: Did you read and follow http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.60/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Cygwin.pod

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that `DBD::Oracle` is installed properly. It's notoriously difficult to get is to work. Basically, you need:

1. install a working(!), properly configured oracle client
2. prepare your environment so you can use the oracle client (especially things like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` need to be set right)
3. fetch the latest `DBD::Oracle` and run `perl Makefile.PL; make` by hand
4. hope...

see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848808/how-to-install-dbdoracle-in-strawberry-perl?rq=1) for more information...

Comment: Can you please tell me how to install Oracle client in cygwin. I dont see an envi variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, where will it be defined? I have to add that there is oracle client installed in the windows system , and my ORACLE_HOME is refereing to that directory, Is that bad? can i reference the same path ?

Comment: sorry, but I don't use windows myself and have consequently no experience with Cygwin...