# Connecting to Oracle from Strawberry Perl

Tags: oracle, perl, cpan, dbi, strawberry-perl

I installed DBD::Oracle from CPAN and tried to use the code below to connect to Oracle DB:

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle;

BEGIN {
    $ENV{ORACLE_HOME} ='C:\instantclient_11_2';   
    $ENV{'NLS_LANG'}='WE8ISO8859P15';
}


my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:host=$host;sid=$sid;port=$port", "$user/$pass", '');
```

But I get the following error message:

```
DBI connect('host=host;sid=mysid;port=1521','user/pass',...) failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate.
Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc. at test.pl line 21
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Worth to mention that I added `C:\instantclient_11_2` to the path environment variable + I created an environment variable `ORACLE_HOME` and set it to `c:\instantclient_11_2`.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848808/how-to-install-dbdoracle-in-strawberry-perl